# CakePHP3.5 load different template file

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.5

In my **PhotoalbumsController** I am trying to load a different layout when the action **imgToAlbum** is called.

```
<?php
namespace App\Controller\Admin;

use App\Controller\AppController;
use Cake\ORM\TableRegistry;
use Cake\Http\ServerRequest;
use Cake\Event\Event;

class PhotoalbumsController extends AppController 
{
    public function initialize()
    {
        parent::initialize();
    }

    ...

    public function imgToAlbum()
    {
        ...        
        $this->viewBuilder()->setLayout('ajax');
        $content = 'test';
        $this->set(compact($content));
    }
```

I am getting this error:

> Error: The view for PhotoalbumsController::imgToAlbum() was not found.
>
> Confirm you have created the file:
>   "Admin/Photoalbums/img_to_album.ctp" in one of the following paths

I've also tried `$this->viewBuilder()->setTemplate('ajax');`
 and `$this->viewBuilder()->template('ajax');`. But these don't work either.

I use the same trick in my **AppController** for my backend, ie, this works:

```
public function beforeRender(Event $event) 
{
    parent::beforeRender($event);
    if($this->request->getParam('prefix') and $this->request->getParam('prefix') == 'admin') {
        $this->viewBuilder()->setLayout('admin');
    }
}
```

What am I missing here.

Comment: Maybe there's code running after the action and before the "before render" stage that changes the layout/template, for example the request handler component!?

Comment: Error is clear. Did you create the file: "Admin/Photoalbums/img_to_album.ctp"?

Comment: @danny3b, you are right, the error is clear. But I should be able to load the ajax.ctp file inside `src/Template/Layout`. While I want to use this file on other controllers too. And it is madness to create a separate file for every controller.

Comment: @ndm, is there a way to check that?

Comment: You could add breakpoints in the view builder. However, as @danny3b pointed out, the error is about a missing (action) template, not about a missing layout, so you may want to rephrase your question, and add information about what filepath exactly you expect to be loaded.

Comment: I don't know what exactly you would like to achieve. Do you need 'ajax' template for ajax calls only? In that scenario the view shouldn't be renderer at all, by setting `$this->autoRender = false;`

Comment: @danny3b, thanks, disabling the autorender works like a charm. Add is as answer please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do a trick:

```
$this->autoRender = false;
```